# Can a user DM another user if they were once blocked but now aren't?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

1. user1 and user2 have a direct message conversation.
2. user2 blocks    user1.
3. user1 blocks user2 and deletes the DM conversation.
4. user1 unblocks user2
5. user2 unblocks user1
6. user2 follows user1
7. user1 **does not follow** user2
8. user2 has a private account
9. user1 has a public account
10. user1 twitter security option: receive message from anyone **is not** checked

Can user2 direct message user1?

Comment: Everything before step 7  is a red herring. In other words, they have no bearing on the final result. Everything comes down to who is following whom (and that "receive messages from anyone" setting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because user1 has a public account and has a setting to receive message from anyone. So user2 can send direct message to user1 even if user1 doesn't follow user2.

But user2 will not be able to send message if user1 has a setting to not receive message from anyone or *only whom I follow*.

Comment: Edited my answer. Do not keep changing the question. Before asking make sure what you really want ask.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't edit it fast enough. That setting is not checked. user1 cannot receive messages from everyone.

Comment: And do not delete comment if you have requested something in comment.

Comment: If user1 has a setting to not recieve message from anyone then user2 would not be able to send message.

Comment: You might want to reword your answer, but I think I agree with you.

Comment: user1 must follow user2 in order to receive a DM